# Responsive File Manager upload issues

Tags: php, file-upload, responsive-filemanager

I've been running the Responsive File Manager recently, both on my local machine as well as a hosted server and have received different issues for each, despite the code being the same. These issues are all related to the uploading of files - currently the tested files have all been only JPEG files, where JPEG files larger than 2 MB are not able to be uploaded.

**Shared issues:**

For both local machine & hosted server, if the uploaded image exceeds 8MB, then I receive the following error message:

> The uploaded file exceeds the max size allowed

**Local machine issues:**

For the local machine only, if the uploaded image is greater than 2MB but less than 8MB, I receive the following error message:

> Warning: mime_content_type(): Empty filename or path in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\webroot\3rdparty\responsive file manager\filemanager\upload.php on line 92

where line 92 refers to this specific line within a set of if statements:

```
if ( ! empty($_FILES) || isset($_POST['url']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['url'])){
        $temp = tempnam('/tmp','RF');
        $handle = fopen($temp, "w");
        fwrite($handle, file_get_contents($_POST['url']));
        fclose($handle);
        $_FILES['file']= array(
            'name' => basename($_POST['url']),
            'tmp_name' => $temp,
            'size' => filesize($temp),
            'type' => explode(".", strtolower($temp))
        );
    }

    $info = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $mime_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    if (function_exists('mime_content_type')){
        $mime_type = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); //line 92
    }
}
```

I also receive this error as well:

> File extension is not allowed. (@C:\xampp\htdocs\project\webroot\3rdparty\responsive file manager\filemanager\upload.php#260)

which refers to this set of if statements:

```
if ( ! empty($_FILES) || isset($_POST['url']))
{
    else // file ext. is not in the allowed list
    {
        response(trans("Error_extension").AddErrorLocation(), 406)->send(); //line 260

        exit();
    }
}
```

**Server issues:**

On the server, those two issues are replaced by this single error:

> Not enough Memory
> (@/home/site/public_html/webroot/3rdparty/responsive file manager/filemanager.upload.php#241)

which refers to this set of if statements:

```
if ( ! empty($_FILES) || isset($_POST['url']))
{
    if (in_array(fix_strtolower($extension), $ext))
    {
        if ($is_img)
        {
            $memory_error = FALSE;
            if ( $extension != 'svg' && !create_img($targetFile, $targetFileThumb, 122, 91))
            {
                $memory_error = TRUE;
            }
            // not enough memory
            if ($memory_error)
            {
                unlink($targetFile);
                response(trans("Not enought Memory").AddErrorLocation(), 406)->send(); //line 241
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Attempts so far:**

I've looked at the following:

- With the file extensions issue on my local machine, I checked the allowed file extensions in the config.php file, but both formats of jpeg were already there:

`'ext_img' => array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'svg' ), //Images`

Meanwhile in include\mime_type_lib.php, both formats of jpeg were already there:

```
$mime_types = array(
    'jpeg'    => 'image/jpeg',
    'jpg'     => 'image/jpeg',
)
```

- On my local machine, I increased the `upload_max_filesize` to 128M. Meanwhile on the server, I used cPanel's PHP settings to do the same thing. Additionally in the config.php file, I changed the MaxSizeUpload setting to match the above changes as follows:

`'MaxSizeUpload' => 128,`

- I did also check against the latest version of config.php and upload.php to see if my versions were outdated, but that wasn't the case.

Comment: `tempnam('/tmp','RF')` generate template file like: `/tmp/RF123.tmp` therefore function `mime_content_type` can't determine mime type... for server issue we don't know which funtion fillup variable `$memory_error`

Comment: `mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);` is wrong because `tmp_name` is file without extension at all, you should check `name` instead also `explode(".", strtolower($temp))` returns an array not string

Comment: If I change `mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);` to `mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['name']);`, I get this error: `mime_content_type(testimage.JPG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\webroot\3rdparty\responsive file manager\filemanager\upload.php on line 92`, while the File extension is not allowed error still remains. I've just added into my question post where `$memory_error` comes from for the server issue.

Comment: ok sorry i take that back, function `mime_content_type` is not well documented... try `echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];` before `mime_content_type`

Comment: Do you mean as follows: `$mime_type = echo mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);` or `$mime_type = mime_content_type(echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);` - either way, both result in syntax errors; first one says `Expected: expression`, second one says `Expected: )`

Comment: I fixed the server issue, courtesy of @KarelWintersky on Github: https://github.com/trippo/ResponsiveFilemanager/issues/362. However, that fix did not work on my local machine.

Comment: `if (function_exists('mime_content_type')){ echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; $mime_type = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); }` to print argument value, because if `tmp_name` is empty then error occurred and why is in: `$_FILES['file']['error']`

Comment: No error shows at all when I attempt to upload the same test image. I get a Tick in the uploader, but the image isn't actually uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ( ! empty($_FILES) || isset($_POST['url']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['url'])){
        if(FALSE === ($temp = tempnam('/tmp','RF'))){
            response(trans("Failed to create temporary file").AddErrorLocation(), 406)->send();
            exit();
        }
        $handle = fopen($temp, "w");
        fwrite($handle, file_get_contents($_POST['url']));
        fclose($handle);
        $explUrl = explode(".", basename($_POST['url']));
        $suffix = array_pop($explUrl);
        $_FILES['file']= array(
            'name' => basename($_POST['url']),
            'tmp_name' => $temp,
            'size' => filesize($temp),
             // type should be mime-type not file suffix
            'type' => $suffix,
            'error' => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
        );
    }

    if($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
        response(trans("Error upload code: ".$_FILES['file']['error']).AddErrorLocation(), 406)->send();
        // error code list: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
        exit();
    }

    if(empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
        response(trans("Error upload").AddErrorLocation(), 406)->send();
        exit();
    }

    $info = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $mime_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    if (function_exists('mime_content_type')){
        $mime_type = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Received this error: `Error upload code: 1 (@C:\xampp\htdocs\project\webroot\3rdparty\responsive file manager\filemanager\upload.php#114)`, with line 114 referring to `response(trans("Error upload code: ".$_FILES['file']['error']).AddErrorLocation(), 406)->send();`. I also changed `'type'` to `$mime_type` as per your comments but that didn't change the error.

Comment: from http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Comment: when you change `upload_max_filesize` you have to restart server

Comment: Good news: It works now for images between 2MB and 8MB. Bad news is that above 8MB I'm getting the memory limit error that I was getting earlier for uploads on the server.

Comment: that's either bad calculation of needed memory or really not enough memory (which can be increased in config), but i looked to `github.com/trippo/ResponsiveFilemanager/issues/362` you posted and the second post is correct not the first one

Comment: Yeah I used the second post to fix the issue on the server. I attempted the same thing on my local machine but it didn't work. On config.php, I did see this comment: `Is possible that if you upload very big images the script not work to overcome this increase the php configuration of memory and time limit`. If it's not `upload_max_filesize`, which would be the correct configurations to change in `php.ini`?
`

Comment: My php.ini `memory_limit` is 1024M. It doesn't seem like that's the issue if it's set that high.

Comment: https://github.com/trippo/ResponsiveFilemanager/blob/f943a483bb13765de087acb795b154dcf38a9490/filemanager/upload.php#L172 and line 180 are the only functions which could cause your error, try something like `if ( $extension != 'svg' && !($ret = create_img($targetFile, $targetFileThumb, 122, 91))) { echo 'Error create_img returns: ' . $ret;` and google what that return code mean and how to avoid that, it's out of descriptiveness here sorry, simply do not upload that big images